# Holomorphic function of several complex variables and sets of zero Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-measure, holomorphic-bundles

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function of $n$ complex variables in region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, with $\Omega \supset \mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is the following statement true?

For any set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lambda(A) = 0$,
$$
\lambda\left(
f^{-1}(f(A)) \cap \mathbb{R}^n
\right)
=
0
.
$$

Comment: For $n\geq 2$, one can probably use the coarea formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Could you elaborate a bit?